# How to increase size of label fonts in barplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have the following *R* code for creating *barplot*:

```
# ... here I read cvs file

mx <- rbind(results$"AVG.P10.")   
colnames(mx) <- results$"RUN"    
rownames(mx) <- "AVG P"    
postscript(file="avg_p_result.ps")    
barplot(mx, beside=T,  col=c("grey"), names.arg= results$"RUN", 
        cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab=1.5)
```

I have tried `cex.lab=1.5` but it does not work at all.

Comment: I can understand that reading online help might seem a tiresome activity at first sight (still, it's very educative and often help to capitalize knowledge on a particular software), but could you at least accept answer(s) you find helpful for your ongoing R activities?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to `?barplot`, you need to use `cex.names=1.5`.

```
barplot(mx, beside=TRUE, col=c("grey"), names.arg=results$"RUN", 
        cex.axis=1.5, cex.names=1.5)
```